# Rails 6 create order confirmation before submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create an order confirmation page for my Rails 6 app. The idea is that user will see a preview of the item they are creating before submitting and the object being saved in the database. Below desired flow:

- User visits /cash_transactions/withdrawals/new
- User enters data and clicks submit
- User is redirected to /cash_transactions/withdrawals/confirm which
  displays the entry
- User clicks confirm to save object to db or cancel
- Object is saved

I followed two main threads that describe this type of action, but they are quite old - [11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903349/order-confirmation-page-in-rails) and [12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445293/ruby-on-rails-confirmation-page-for-activerecord-object-creation) years old. Nevertheless based on that I've created below code:

```
# controllers/cash_transactions/withdrawals_controller.tb

module CashTransactions
  class WithdrawalsController < CashTransactions::BaseController

    (...)

    def confirm
      @cash_transaction = CashTransaction.new(cash_transaction_params)

      render 'cash_transactions/_confirm'
    end
  end
end

# routes.rb

  namespace :cash_transactions do
    resources :withdrawals, only: %i[new create] do
      collection do
        post :confirm
      end
    end
  end
```

With corresponding views:

```
# app/views/cash_transactions/new.html.erb

<%= render 'cash_transactions/form', cash_transaction: @cash_transaction %>


# views/cash_transactions/_form
# the form is rendered for cash_transaction create action

<%= simple_form_for cash_transaction, url: { action: :confirm } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :amount %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit' %>
<% end %>


# confirmation page under views/cash_transactions/_confirm.html.erb

<div>
  Total of withdrawal: <%= @cash_transaction.amount.to_i %>
</div>

<%= link_to 'Confim', cash_transactions_withdrawals_path(@cash_transaction), method: :post %>
<%= link_to 'Cancel', cash_transactions_path %>
```

And everything works until the user clicks `confirm` button in `views/cash_transactions/_confirm.html.erb` - instead of creating a record an error appears:

> param is missing or the value is empty: cash_transaction
> Did you mean?
> authenticity_token
> action
> controller
> _method

where did I go wrong? or there is a completely different way to do so?

Comment: The code here doesn't actually show how you are rendering the form.  Check the `name` attributes of the inputs in the rendered HTML. `render 'cash_transactions/_confirm'` is also pretty smelly. If you're rendering it from the controller then its not a partial.

Comment: @max I don't get it, after all it shows how the form is rendered here - `# views/cash_transactions/_form`. And that's it, there is only one input and one button inside of this form.

Comment: No it doesn't, there is no `render partial: 'form', ...` which shows how you are passing the variable.

Comment: @max It's pretty standard - `<%= render 'cash_transactions/form', cash_transaction: @cash_transaction %>` inside of `app/views/cash_transactions/new.html.erb`. Question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl/dr: You need to add parameters to your create request.

**Why this is happening**

The `/confirm` view is being rendered with an (unsaved) `@cash_transaction` object, however that object is not being used and so the information is being lost when the page is rendered.

The line:

```
<%= link_to 'Confim', cash_transactions_withdrawals_path(@cash_transaction), method: :post %>
```

Will submit a `POST` request with no parameters to the `/cash_transactions/withdrawals#create` (because you've given it no parameters to post). It doesn't know to include the params from the previous request.

There are a few options to fix this... you can add params as URL parameters in link_to [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414663/using-rails-link-to-for-links-that-post), however I wouldn't recommend posting with params in the URL.

You can use [`button_to`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) instead, and pass in the `cash_transaction` arguments from the previous request in the `params:` option (or pull them out of the unsaved @cash_transaction object).

Approach #1 - reuse create params

```
# Get them from the params sent in the previous request. In the controller...
  def create
    @cash_transaction = CashTransaction.create!(cash_transaction_params)
    # etc...
  end
  #...
  protected

  def cash_transaction_params
    params[:cash_transaction].permit(:amount, :whatever)
  end
  helper_method :cash_transaction_params
# In the view
<%= button_to 'Confirm', {action: 'create', params: cash_transaction_params}
```

Approach #2 - Access attributes from the model you built

```
<%= button_to 'Confirm', {action: 'create', params: @cash_transaction.attributes.slice('amount', 'other_attribute') }
```

Or you could do something like render the form again but hidden and have the "confirm" button submit the hidden form (with `{ action: :create }` instead of `{ action: :confirm}`). This last solution is probably the easiest to understand.

Comment: I'm getting an error: `unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash` with `button_to`

Comment: You can use `params[:cash_transaction].permit!` or whitelist them. Getting the parameters from the model is a good idea through.

Comment: I'll update w/ an example of getting them from the model - just keep in mind you need to keep it in sync with the `/new` form or the fields they submit won't actually be used.

Comment: @max @meicher guys, don't you think this `confirm` method should be GET instead of POST ? EOD it it behaves exactly the same as `new` method.

Comment: Could be. You can’t post form data with a “get”, and I dislike sending form data in URL params… but it’s an option.  I’d probably use a post myself but wouldn’t think too hard about it. In actuality I’d probably handle this with a confirmation modal and not push anything to the backend until the user confirms it (or create the thing in an unconfirmed status)

Comment: GET would be wrong as its not really a idempotent request.